# Can I award myself a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, self-answer

On this site you can bounty a question in order to receive more attention. Then the OP can choose who deserves to receive the bounty.

You can also answer a question you asked yourself, which, in some contexts, is very useful.

My question is: if you answer your own question, can you add a bounty to the question and award it to yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you won't get the reputation back from the bounty.

That's in place to prevent the obvious trick of keeping bounties open and drawing attention to your questions for free.

Comment: Once upon a time you could, but you can no longer assign the bounty to yourself. - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/172958